getMapAsync doesn`t work. Why can`t access to class 'com.tomtom.sdk.common.Cancellable'? TomTom
I'm trying to add map with TomTom API in my android app but I can't. I watched videos, guides and couldn`t find solution. I set up the project correctly according to the instructions.
In MapActivity I can't use getMapAsync because of an error:

"Cannot access class 'com.tomtom.sdk.common.Cancellable'.
Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"


XML code:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MapActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

MapActivity code in kotlin:
public class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var tomtomMap:TomTomMap
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle ?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

        val mapOptions = MapOptions(mapKey = "@strings/API_KEY_TOMTOM");
        val mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment)
            .commit()

        mapFragment.getMapAsync{map->
            tomtomMap=map
            enableUserLocation()
            setUpMapListener()
        }

    }

    private fun setUpMapListener() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    private fun enableUserLocation() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

Build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}
val tomtomApiKey: String by project
android {
    namespace = "com.example.###"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.###"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    packaging {
        jniLibs.pickFirsts.add("lib/**/libc++_shared.so")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    buildTypes.configureEach {
        buildConfigField("String", "TOMTOM_API_KEY", "###")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui)
    implementation(libs.firebase.storage)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    annotationProcessor("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0")

    val version = "0.50.6"
    implementation("com.tomtom.sdk.maps:map-display:$version")
}

Settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://repositories.tomtom.com/artifactory/maven")
        }
    }
}


com.tomtom.sdk.common is a dependency for map-display. Did you have any other issues related to downloading it?
